# Unknown server tag 'Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I'm building a web part in SharePoint 2010, and I need to use the TaxonomyFieldControl for filtering. I have set the reference in the project (the one that isnt 'intl', v14.0.0.0), but I get a warning: "Element 'TaxonomyFieldControl' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing." at compilation, and at runtime I get "Unknown server tag 'Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl'"

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Taxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebPart_DocumentsUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test.WebPart_Documents.WebPart_DocumentsUserControl" %>
...
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="TaxonomyFilter" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl>
```

it is also worth noting that "Taxonomy" does not appear with Intellisense, and neither does "Utilities", but the rest do. Also in the code-behind, i have:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;
```

and it compiles fine.

I have tried deleting my schema cache per http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/07/21/95.aspx

Thank you!

Comment: Try the `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` like so: http://blog.hagenberg-software.at/2010/06/adding-the-taxonomy-control-to-a-custom-page/ or so http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/build-your-own-user-interface-components-using-the-taxonomy-controls/

Comment: doesn't help... it seems Visual Studio isn't actually registering Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're registering the wrong assembly. Instead of:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Taxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy"
             Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                       PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Try:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Taxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy"
             Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                       PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I never resolved this and either moved on to something else or built the web part a different way - and as such I have no way to confirm that your solution works! But it looks like it would work, so I'll mark it as right!

Comment: Thanks - I completely forgot to look at the post date when I replied :) Didn't realize it was such an old post.